# Search for var in external page

Tags: object

I want to make a script that search for a variable in a external page.
For example, i want the script to visit this page: [Here](https://billing.dacentec.com/hostbill/index.php?/cart/dedicated-servers/), 
Check whether a server is available and notify me somehow.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you explain more detailed what you are trying to do? Its not very clear if you are trying to find existing variables inside of other JavaScript files, or in whole webpages.

Comment: do you want to know if a variable is created in the source of a js file of a webpage or do you want to know if a variable exists in the js is executed in the documents namespace ?

Comment: I want to find a text for example, in a web page... And, if exists, the script tell me

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to recuperate the text of the source of a page. Then search for any strings that we want in that source. Just add another `search` call to extend the search. Works in Firefox.

```
<script>
function print(text) {
    alert(text);
}

function search(where, what) {
    var position = where.indexOf(what)
    if ( position !== -1) {
        print("Found \"" + what + "\" at " + position);
        return;
    } //else
    print("\"" + what + "\" not found");
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://billing.dacentec.com/hostbill/index.php?/cart/dedicated-servers/", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var externalText = xhr.responseText;
      search(externalText, "technology");
      search(externalText, "secure");
      search(externalText, "we");
    } else {
      print(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  print(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);


</script>
```